# A certain non-clean ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

I am searching for a non-commutative ring $R$ with identity such that $R$ is not a clean ring and $R/Soc(R_R)$ is a Boolean ring. By a clean ring I mean a ring each of whose elements is a sum of a unit and an idempotent, and by Boolean ring I mean a ring each of whose elements is an idempotent.

Thanks for any help and suggestion!

Comment: [Crosspost](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2113142/29335)